# Turn an array format string into actual Array on PHP

Tags: php

I am struggling to find the solution for converting string type array into actual array. I have a database column where it stores plain-text exactly like below :

```
array ( 'mc_gross' => '100.00', 'auth_exp' => '18:35:24 Apr 08, 2022 PDT',  
 'protection_eligibility' => 'Eligible', 'payer_id' => 'J4RS8Q76ZEKZ2', 'payment_date' =>                        '17:35:24 Mar 10, 2022 PST', 'payment_status' => 'Pending', 'charset' => 'UTF-8',  
 'first_name' => 'John', 'transaction_entity' => 'auth', 'quantity' => '4',)
```

I need to access 'quantity' value from this column. I have tried to fetch database and then tried to access it through the code below:

```
while($resp=$db->fetch($response)){
                foreach ($resp as $key => $value) {
                    $gateway[] = $resp[$key];
                    }
                }
            }
        echo $gateway[0]['quantity'];
```

I am getting 'a' after this command. it is the first character of string as you see.

The output of `echo $gateway[0]` is :

```
array ( 'mc_gross' => '100.00', 'auth_exp' => '18:35:24 Apr 08, 2022 PDT',  
 'protection_eligibility' => 'Eligible', 'payer_id' => 'J4RS8Q76ZEKZ2', 'payment_date' =>                        '17:35:24 Mar 10, 2022 PST', 'payment_status' => 'Pending', 'charset' => 'UTF-8',  
 'first_name' => 'John', 'transaction_entity' => 'auth', 'quantity' => '4',)
```

I have tried to access by : `$gateway[0][1]` (just for example) but this only shows me : `a`

As you see it is saved as string, I don't know how to handle this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How you printed this output (what you use to print ) from `$gateway`? Have you tried `$gateway[0][7]`?

Comment: Why you trying to access value of the `key` => `( $dateway[0][11] )` which obviously does not exist in this array?

Comment: I mean that I have tried everything but the only result I get is the first symbol of the value `$gateway[0]` . It looks like an array but it is only a string and therefore accessing as an array not works at all. it only returns me the symbols. Is there any way to convert it to an array ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    'mc_gross' => '100.00',
    'auth_exp' => '18:35:24 Apr 08, 2022 PDT',
    'protection_eligibility' => 'Eligible',
    'payer_id' => 'J4RS8Q76ZEKZ2',
    'payment_date' => '17:35:24 Mar 10, 2022 PST',
    'payment_status' => 'Pending',
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'transaction_entity' => 'auth',
    'quantity' => '4',
] // this is $gateway[0]
```

Simply use:

```
$gateway[0]['quantity']
```

to get the quantity value

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work also. Because the result of that command is : 'a' . As I said before $garteway[0] contains long string looks like array but it is not. It is a string and needs to be serialized in my opinion.

Comment: I answered according to your question. Please add required code to your question so we can help you better.

Comment: I have edited my first question, please have a look.

Comment: Did you try to run json_decode on your "string like array"

Comment: To be honest I have tried but that did not work also, but might be I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try json_decode($gateway)[0]['quantity'] or just json_decode($gateway) ? I think $gateway is string and once you check [0] it returns array's "a". However, It shouldn't be like that. PHP do not convert it like "array(.....)" I think there is something wrong with the source string

Comment: `$requantity=  json_decode($gateway) ; echo $requantity;` - tried this and another one you mentioned but shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The *'string type arrays'* are so-called **associative arrays**.

The result of `$gateway[0]` is such an associative array. More precise your array `$gateway` contains another associative array at its first index `[0]`. Therefore using

```
 $gateway[0]['quantity']
```

would be your way to go.

---

As a bonus tip you should check the array documentation of php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work also. Because the result of that command is : 'a' . As I said before $garteway[0] contains long string looks like array but it is not. It is a string and needs to be serialized in my opinion.

Comment: What's the output you get of `gettype($gateway[0])` and `gettype($gateway[0]['quantity'])` ?